# Stacking divs on small screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar .container {
        width: 1170px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .navbar .nav > li > a {
        padding: 10px 8px 10px 8px;
    }
    .navbar .nav > li > a.training {
        padding-right: 8px;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1034px) {
  .navbar .nav > li > a {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
  }
 }



@media (min-width: 980px) {
    .callout .callout-inner {
        min-height: 155px;
    }

}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
    body {

    }
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .front .callout .callout-inner {
        padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    }



    .front .callout h2 {
        margin-top: 12px;
    }
    .front .report-callout h2 {
        font-size: 26px;
        margin: 0 0px 41px 0;
    }
    .front .report-callout .callout-inner {
        padding: 30px 5px 11px 22px;
    }

    .nav-collapse{
        float: right;
    }
    .nav-collapse.in.collapse {
        float: right;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 11px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 11px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
        box-shadow:         0px 11px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
        position: absolute;
        top: 58px;
        right: 20px;
    }
    .nav-collapse {
        position: absolute;
        top: 58px;
        right: 20px;
    }
    .navbar .btn-navbar {
        margin-top: 22px;
    }
    .navbar li.contact .dropdown-menu {
        display: block!important;
    }
    .navbar .dropdown {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        box-shadow:         0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    .navbar li.contact .dropdown-menu {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        box-shadow:         0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    .page-contact-hcc .navbar li.contact a.contact-hcc
    , .page-contact-list .navbar li.contact a.contact-hcc
    , .page-report-incident .navbar li.contact a.contact-hcc {
        color: #828282;
    }
    .navbar li.contact .dropdown-menu {
        border-radius: 0;
        border-left: 0px;

    }
    .navbar li.contact .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        padding: 9px 8px;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    .navbar .nav li.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle .caret {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar li.contact .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover
    , .navbar li.contact .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus
    , .navbar li.contact .dropdown-submenu:hover > a
    , .navbar li.contact .dropdown-submenu:focus > a
    , .page-contact-list .navbar li.contact a.contact-list
    , .page-report-incident .navbar li.contact a.report-incident{
        color: #b5000b;
        background-color: #f2f2f2!important;


        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
}
/** wider than iPad portrait **/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .nav {
        margin: 20px 0 0 0px;;
    }
    #hero-bg {
        background: #e2e2e2 ;
        height: 290px;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
.sidebar-callout img {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
/** iPad Portrait **/
@media (width: 768px) {
    .front [class*="span"]
    ,.page-contact-hcc .contact-span {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .front .row
    ,.page-contact-hcc .contact-row {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .front .callout h2 {
        margin-top: 21px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-collapse.in.collapse {
        float: right;
    }
    .side-nav {
        display: none;
    }
    .front .callout h2 {
        margin-top: 21px;
    }
    .footer .copyright {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .callout .sidebar-callout {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

}
/** smaller than iPad portrait **/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    #main .row{
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;

    }
    #main {

    }

    .hero
    ,#main .row
    ,footer {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .hero {
        height: 265px;

        background-size: 100% 316px;
    }
    .hero-callout {
        width: 420px;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

    }
    .modal-header {
        padding:0px 15px;           
    }
    .modal-header h3 {
        font-size:14px;
                    
    }
    .modal-body{
        padding:0px;
    }    
}

/** iPhone landscape and smaller **/
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #main .row{
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;

    }
    #main {

    }
    .interior-header h1 {
        font-size: 27.5px;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-inner {
        height: 60px;
    }
    .navbar .brand {
        width: 70%;
    }
    .front .callout h2 {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .navbar .btn-navbar {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    .navbar .brand {
        padding: 15px 0 0px 0;
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner {
        height: 65px;
    }
    .front .hero-callout h2{
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 5px 0 5px 16px;
    }
    .front .hero-callout p {
        line-height: 15px;
        margin: 0px 15px 10px 15px;
    }
    .hero-callout .badge-updated {
        font-size: 9px;
        line-height: 12px;
        padding-right: 6px;
        padding-left: 6px;
    }
    .hero {
        position: relative;
        height: 130px;
        background: #e2e2e2 url('../images/hcc/hero-bg.jpg') no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        padding: 0px 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    #RecentlyUpdatedArea {
        height:100px;
    }

    .hero-callout {
        width: 98%;

        position: absolute;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        top: 20px;
        left: 4px;
    }
    .front .report-callout .callout-inner {
        padding: 15px 5px 11px 22px;
    }
    .front .report-callout h2 {
        font-size: 21px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .front .report-callout p {
        padding-right: 0px;
    }

    a.change-filter {
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
    .interior-header h1{
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    .interior-header h1, .current-region {
        padding-left:  15px;
        line-height: 65px;
    }

    .current-region, .current-sector {
        font-size: 70%;
    }
    .report-incident-contant {

        padding: 20px 10px 20px 12px;
    }
    .grey-stripes p {
        font-size: 23px;
        line-height: 22px;
        top: 25px;
        left: 10px;
    }
    .red-block p{
        left: 8px;

    }
    .grey-stripes a, .red-block p, .red-block a {
        font-size: 28px;
        line-height: 29px;
        top: 33px;
    }
    #interior-bg {
        height: 65px;
        top: 60px;
    }
    .interior-header {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .btn.btn-large.btn-credo-hotline {
        padding: 35px 35px;
    }
    .filter {
        font-size:16px;
        line-height:25px;
        padding-left:15px;
    }
    .modal-header {
        padding:0px 15px;           
    }
    .modal-header h3 {
        font-size:14px;
                    
    }
    .modal-body{
        padding:0px;
    }
    

}

body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #6e7075;
    position: relative;
    
}

.footerlinks{
 display:inline-block
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.active-arrow {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation = 3);
}
.btn-large [class^="icon-"], .btn-large [class*=" icon-"] {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
p {
    font-family: Georgia1, Georgia, serif;
}
.hero-callout-bg {
    display: block;
}
.hero-callout  {
    width: 539px;
    height: 210px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
}

.hero-callout h2 {
    color: #828282;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.hero-callout .badge-updated {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: #009bd4;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.front .callout {
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    background: #FFF;
}
.front .callout h2 {
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 0;

}
.front .callout .callout-inner {
    /*cursor: pointer;*/

    padding: 35px 20px 0 20px;
}
.red-brd, .front .callout .callout-inner, .training-content, .sidebar-callout, .report-incident-contant {
    border-left: 3px solid #b5000b;
}
.front .hero-callout .callout-inner {
    background: url('../images/hcc/transparent-bg.png') repeat;

    padding: 5px 5px 0 10px;
}
.front .hero-callout .callout-inner .btn {
    text-shadow: none;
}
.front .hero-callout h2, .front .hero-callout p {
    margin: 15px;
    color: #6e7075 !important;
}
.front .callout .align-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    width: 73px;
}
.front .callout p {
    margin-left: 94px;
}
.front .callout a.view-all {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
a.view-all {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.front .report-callout {
    background: url('../images/hcc/grey_pattern.jpg') #6F7075 repeat-x;
    color: #FFF;
    background-position: bottom;
    min-height: 154px;

}
.front .report-callout .callout-inner {
    padding: 30px 22px 11px 22px;
}
.front .report-callout h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0px 20px 0;
    width: 135px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
.front .report-callout p {

    padding-right: 5px;
}
.front .report-callout .btn{
    text-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 7px 15px;
}

#interior-bg {
    width: 100%;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    height: 138px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.interior-header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.section-html-content .interior-header {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.interior-header h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #828282;
    line-height: 120px;
    font-size: 31.5px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.interior-header div.hands {

}
.interior-header .hands img {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.filter {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #6e7075;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 31px;
}
a.change-filter {
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #b5000b;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.modal-filter .modal-body {
    z-index: 999999;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
table.table {

    padding: 30px;
}
table thead tr {
    background: #FFF;
}
.doc-table thead th.title {
    padding-left: 36px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
table td{
    border-top: 5px solid #FFF ;

}
.table td {
    border-top: 0px;
}


.doc-table td div.pdf
,.doc-table td div.video {
    padding-left: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.training-content {
    padding: 30px;
    background: #FFF;


}
.callout .sidebar-callout {
    background: #FFF;

    padding: 25px 10px 0 25px;
    min-height: 170px !important;
}
.sidebar-callout p.lead {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.sidebar-callout img {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.side-nav .nav-list {
    border-left: 4px solid #b5000b;
}
.side-nav .nav-list > li > a {
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
}
.page-contact-hcc .side-nav .nav-list > li.contact-hcc > a
,.page-contact-list .side-nav .nav-list > li.contact-list > a
,.page-report-incident .side-nav .nav-list > li.report-incident > a
,.side-nav .nav-list > li > a:hover
,.side-nav .nav-list > li.active > a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #b5000b;
}
.page-contact-hcc .form-wrapper {
    border-left: 3px solid #b5000b;
    background: #FFF;

}
.page-contact-hcc .form-wrapper {
    padding: 22px 20px 20px 35px;
}
.btn.btn-large.btn-credo-hotline {
    padding: 35px 58px;
    font-size: 31px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

        
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    #StaticContentArea table, 
    #StaticContentArea thead, 
    #StaticContentArea tbody, 
    #StaticContentArea th, 
    #StaticContentArea td, 
    #StaticContentArea tr { 
        display: block; 
    }
 
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    #StaticContentArea thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }
 
    #StaticContentArea tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
 
    #StaticContentArea td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
        white-space: normal;
        text-align:left;
    }
    
 
    #StaticContentArea td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 20px;
        left: 1em;
        width: 35%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
 
    /*
    Label the data
    */
    #StaticContentArea td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <!--template bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div class="hero-callout hero-callout-bg" id="RecentlyUpdatedArea">
            <div class="callout-inner clearfix">
                <h2 id="RecentlyUpdatedNumber">
                    RECENTLY UPDATED
                    <span class="badge badge-info badge-updated">
                        <a id="RecentlyUpdatedPop" ng-reflect-router-link="/content/recentUpd" ng-reflect-href="#/content/recentUpd" href="#/content/recentUpd">0</a>
                    </span>
                </h2>
                <p>Stay in the know with all that’s changing within HCC&amp;P—access all items added or updated within the last 30 days.</p>
                <p><a class="view-all" ng-reflect-router-link="/content/recentUpd" ng-reflect-href="#/content/recentUpd" href="#/content/recentUpd">View All<span class="arrow-btn">»</span></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="right" class="span6 clearfix" style="margin-top: 40px">
        <div class="clearfix" id="custom-search-input">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                        <i class="icon-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the below HTML (I just inserted the search box) and I want them to stack on small screens. I have to stay in version 2.3.2. Using the default CSS and JS, no customization. Right now, these two divs get merged on small screens. I want them to stack.

```
<div class="hero">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <div *ngFor="let x of Items" id="A" class="hero-callout hero-callout-bg">
                    <div class="callout-inner clearfix">
                        <h2 id="n">
                            {{x.title}}
                            <span class="badge badge-info badge-updated">
                                <a id="RP" [routerLink]="x.routerLink">{{Count}}</a>
                            </span>
                        </h2>
                        <p>{{x.text}}</p>
                        <p><a [routerLink]="x.routerLink" class="view-all">{{x.text}}<span class="arrow-btn">»</span></a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6 clearfix" align="right" style="margin-top: 40px">
                <div id="custom-search-input" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                                <i class="icon-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Output HTML:

```
<div class="hero">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <!--template bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div class="hero-callout hero-callout-bg" id="RecentlyUpdatedArea">
            <div class="callout-inner clearfix">
                <h2 id="RecentlyUpdatedNumber">
                    RECENTLY UPDATED
                    <span class="badge badge-info badge-updated">
                        <a id="RecentlyUpdatedPop" ng-reflect-router-link="/content/recentUpd" ng-reflect-href="#/content/recentUpd" href="#/content/recentUpd">0</a>
                    </span>
                </h2>
                <p>Stay in the know with all that’s changing within HCC&amp;P—access all items added or updated within the last 30 days.</p>
                <p><a class="view-all" ng-reflect-router-link="/content/recentUpd" ng-reflect-href="#/content/recentUpd" href="#/content/recentUpd">View All<span class="arrow-btn">»</span></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="right" class="span6 clearfix" style="margin-top: 40px">
        <div class="clearfix" id="custom-search-input">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                        <i class="icon-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output:
[Output on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpoYG.png)

Comment: @ZimSystem: Please wait for the response before voting something down.

Comment: can you add your css too

Comment: because without your css. they would seem to work fine.

Comment: so add your css too

Comment: I learned after your comment that if I use this HTML out of context, it does stack. But something is wrong there that is preventing it with all the details, please check the attached image. Now I am thinking could it be the Hero background or the CSS related to that that may be causing it.

Comment: @AnujaAgarwal: there is no special CSS, just the Bootstrap2.3.2 CSS. I refer from here:

Comment: @anujaAgarwal: Sorry, new to stackoverflow- here is the link https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2

Comment: yeah that's why you need to add css to your question like you did with your html, otherwise there are maybe 100 posibble reasons. can't guess by just an image.

Comment: ok. please give me some time

Comment: @AnujaAgarwal- Understood. Is that CSS link enough?

Comment: @AnujaAgarwal- I just took another look and there are two more custom CSS that has hero class properties. While I am working on that, here are the details in there:

Comment: yeah it is enough

Comment: I didn't down vote it! Don't assume before you comment.

Comment: @ZimSystem- point well taken. Again, I am new here so cant figure out who exactly did that.

Comment: @AnujaAgarwal- updated with CSS

Comment: Is that all of the CSS? The divs still stack ok: http://www.bootply.com/Cvqq3JnYJ8

Comment: @ZimSystem- I only privided CSS relatd to the Hero, there two CSS files. Should I upload all the content from both? ok doing it anyways...

Answer (score 0):

Edit the second span6 div (the one containing search bar) like this, adding the `id="searchSpan"`

```
<div id="searchSpan" align="right" class="span6 clearfix" style="margin-top: 40px;">
```

Add add this to your custom css:

```
@media (max-width:768px){
  div.row-fluid>div.span6{
    clear:both;
  }
  #searchSpan{
    float:left;
  }
}
```

Comment: This did not work though I can see that these are in effect under Elements (dev tool) but still it does not change the behavior.

Comment: maybe it's caused by some other library you are using. it is working in mine. I will send you screen shot of their computed styles. compare them with yours.